# Given a probability, and a desired percent chance of having the result, how can I find a constant that can be used to find other probabilties?

Tags: probability

Hard to describe within the title alone.

If we are given a probability in the form $(1-\frac1a)^b$ and we are interested in that probability having a 50% of having happened at least once, we can write $(1-\frac1a)^b=0.5$

If we try a few values, we can get pretty close through trial and error $(1-\frac{1}{2500})^{1723}\approx0.5$ and we can get closer and closer with larger numbers.

If we take the $a$ and $b$ values we just found and found the ratio between them, we get $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{1723}{2500}=0.6892$

What I noticed is that constant $0.6892$, which appears to just be an approximation of some more precise constant, works to find what another probability in the above defined form needs to use for $b$ given $a$ or $a$ given $b$. I.E. $a=480000$ then $0.6892*480000=330816$ which means $(1-\frac{1}{480000})^{330816}\approx0.5$ which holds true.

Ultimately, my question is, how can I find that exact constant for a 50% chance of the given probability having happened at least once, or more generally, any arbitrary % chance of a given probability having happened at least once?

Note: I was given this comment when I posted in the wrong Math stackexchange:
"You refer to "that exact constant", but I'm not sure that you have defined a constant. I think you are observing that $(1−1/a)^b$ is not terribly approximated by $(1−1/(na))^{nb}$, so that, in the limit as $n→∞$, we get $e^{b/a}$. Then you are looking for $b/a≈ln(2)≈0.6931$. Is that correct?" (Thanks @LSpice!)

And yes, for 50%, $ln(2)$ seems to be the right "constant", but I am curious about a general way of finding that value for any given percent chance, like 30, 75, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $a$ and $b$ be any real numbers, not just integers, and say that $b$ is proportional to $a$: $b=ka$:

$(1-\frac{1}{a})^{b}=((1-\frac{1}{a})^{a})^{k}$

If we make $a$ large, then $(1-\frac{1}{a})^{a}$ is very close to $e^{-1}$, so $((1-\frac{1}{a})^{a})^{k}$ is approximately $e^{-k}$. So what you are really asking is how to solve $e^{-k}=p$ for some proportion $p$. And the answer to that is $-k=ln(p)$.
So the general formula for the ratio ($k$) you are looking for is just $-ln(p)$.

Comment: Rather, that's a good first guess. The exact $k$ is $\ln(p)/(a \ln(1-1/a))$, which tends to $-\ln(p)$ as $a$ gets large, but in a real problem will always be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constant.

An event occurs with $(1-\frac 1{a})$, and you want to know how many times in succession the event must occur  to give a probability of $0.5$,

or to phrsase it more neatly, what value of *n* will give $p^n=0.5$

So for your example, the answer to as man decimal points as you want will be given by $(2499/2500)^n = 0.5$

and by taking logs of both sides, the answer is $n\approx1732.52$

For $p = \frac{479999}{480000}\quad n \approx 332710$

fo your oriinal example, suppose we wanted
$\left(\frac{2499}{2500}\right)^n = 0.3$,

taking logs of both sides and solving, we get $n \approx 3009.33$

Comment: You are not wrong with your numbers. But what I was looking for is what number, when multiplied by $2500$ in this case, but really any number as part of the probability, would result in that $n\approx1732.52$ when we know we want the percent chance that the event will happen at least once to be 50%, $0.5$. That number would be the same no matter what the denominator was, for example, $480000*c\approx332710$ and for both example, $c\approx0.69314$

Comment: The point is '*That number would be the same no matter what the denominator was*" is not true. It will approach that number as $n$ tends to infinity. So if we are dealing with, say, $(1- \frac13)^b = 0.5,  b/a \approx 0.57\;\;$!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now! Apologies. I suppose the number I was looking for was the limit at $n->\infty$ as you pointed out.